# Pine Script version 5. Compilation error with the following code. What should i do to get it working?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
//@version=5

strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)
sma50 = ta.sma(close, 50)
sma200 = ta.sma(close, 200)
rsiValue = ta.rsi(close, 14)

buySignal = ta.cross(close, sma50) and ta.cross(close, sma200) and rsiValue >= 45 and rsiValue <= 55

exitSignal = rsiValue > 70


if (buySignal)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (exitSignal)
    strategy.exit("Exit Long", "Long")

plot(sma50, color=color.orange, linewidth=2)
plot(sma200, color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
plot(rsiValue, color=color.purple, linewidth=2)

// Plot buy and sell signals
plotshape(buySignal, style=shape.arrowup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(exitSignal, style=shape.arrowdown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.tiny)
```

I tried commenting some of the code and found that "if" conditions when commented the code works and the lines are plotted but when if is to be rendered the code stops working.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear.

> strategy.exit must have at least one of the following parameters:
> 'profit', 'limit', 'loss', 'stop' or one of the following pairs:
> 'trail_offset' and 'trail_price' / 'trail_points'. To close the
> position at market price, use 'strategy.close'

You cannot use `strategy.exit()` without an exit price.

If you want to close your position based on a condition, you should use `strategy.close()` instead.